# Apache Rewrite rule confusion

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, rule

I'm trying to convert a simple url (below) in to a blog-style url, but not quite sure how to do it, all of my other rules are working fine, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

URL I want to convert: http://www.website.com/myblog.php?id=1&title=My+blog+title

URL I want it to create: http://www.website.com/1/my-blog-title

What should the rule be?

Any assistance appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/([^.]+) myblog.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

Comment: Hi Lizard, after further messing around and investigation, I've decided on using this one, checking the numeric value made the difference. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/]+)$ myblog.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

But here the hyphens are not replaced by plus signs.

Answer (score 1):

in your .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /myblog.php?id=$1 [L]
```

You don't (well shouldn't) need to pass the blog title to the blog file, only the ID. Hope this works

Comment: Superb thank you, this out of the three seemed to work. Not sure why the others didn't, maybe the way I explained the requirement. But thanks all!

Comment: you're very welcome. While I cannot give a definite answer without some trial and error with the bottoom two, it could very well be the lack of a / in the destination path which establishes the path to originate from the html docroot dir.

one quick thing, make sure you sanitize $_GET['id'] before passing it off to a mySQL query.